# Can't make line-spacing in DIV like as in TEXTAREA?

Tags: html, css

I've found that we can use DIV as a TEXTAREA by setting contenteditable='true' and overflow='auto' (or 'scroll') (I don't care about the appearance, just the functionality), but I really can't find the solution with Google search to make it really like a TEXTAREA, the problem is related to line-spacing, when pressing enter key, the next line is too distant from the one before in DIV. When designing with DreamWeaver, if I try editing the DIV's content and pressing enter key and switch to the code window, I can see there are P tags automatically inserted. That's why the lines in DIV are too distant from each other and it can't look fine like in a TEXTAREA. I want to say that it is so ugly and awkward.

Could you please let me know how to suppress that nasty automatic insertion of P tag into DIV's content whenever pressing Enter key? Or could you give me any other solution to make the lines in DIV normal as in TEXTAREA?

Thank you very much!
Your help would be highly appreciated! (I'm just a newbie in Web programming, so please be patient!!! Thankssss!! :))

UPDATE!!!
You may all misunderstood me, when I say I press the Enter key, it is not in code editor like DreamWeaver, It is when I load the page in the browser and try typing as a normal user. That's when I test the page.

Comment: Got any code? An example somewhere? Why not just use a textarea?

Comment: This is a Dreamweaver issue, not a css or html issue.

Comment: Have you tried <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Comment: Yeah, if you're designing with Dreamweaver, ALWAYS use a real browser to test in. It's live view bs cannot be trusted.

Comment: I think you all misunderstood me, I'm coding with notepad, and then tried dreamweaver to see what is really in the DIV after typing some lines in the DIV using the designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the strange problem (which might make some of you think I'm noob?, vote down me?) was not the fault of mine, it was the fault of the browser I was using, it was Opera browser. I didn't think it renders the DIV's content that way.

After try using a different browser like Google Chrome, FireFox and it is normal now, like a TEXTAREA as I want.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for digging this up so late, but you should look into Normalising the styles across all browsers. The [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) is a great baseline, and has a stylesheet called _normalise.css_ which does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
#myDiv p{
    margin: 0px;
}
```

I'm not 100% sure that the margin is what is causing the line height issues, you may want to try changing `height`, `padding`, etc. until you figure it out.

I tried making a fiddle and I'm not having the same problem, line spacing looks normal to me: http://jsfiddle.net/dFzjT/
Upon closer inspection, Chrome is adding extra `div`s upon each newline.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to edit in the code view instead of the WYSIWYG HTML editor. Then you will want to type in between the opening and closing div tags:

```
<div>your text here.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing.

A lot of the answers on here answer the question, but they all miss an important point.
We were all new to this at some point.

So let me give you some advice that I wish I got when I started down this road.

- Learn to read *the code*, and your life will be easier.

  It might seem daunting now, but trust in your own ability to learn, and just struggle for a few days. You'll come out on the other end with a headache and a smile.
- Write the code, save, and refresh the page in your browser.

  This way, you look at it in a browser.
  You should also get yourself all the important browsers: [Chrome](http://chrome.google.com), [Firefox](http://getfirefox.com), [Internet Explorer](http://ie.microsoft.com/), [Opera](http://www.opera.com/download/) & [Safari](http://www.apple.com/safari/).
- Learn to use a *localhost* server like MAMP / XAMPP / Visual Studio.

  This way you can write server-side code; that way you can test, check and tweak - all without having to upload anything.

Most of all, though..

- **Stay away from the WYSIWYG.**

  They're all just bad news.

  *Just write your own code.*

:{D

Comment: Sorry but when you don't have any understanding about how the browsers render DIV's content, you can't do anything. All I know about how to make DIV like a textarea is setting two attributes I mentioned in my question to appropriate values, I don't know if it involves any other style attributes. And I can't try anything, not a clue at all. Please understand me.

Comment: I understand. Let Dreamweaver add the `<p>` tags around your sentences. Now, give your `<div>` an id, eg: `<div id="myTextArea">`, then, in the `<head>` of your document add: `<style>#myTextArea p {margin:0;line-height:1em}</style>`. Hope this helps.